# Rails cucumber simple test, step redirect after login_as

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cucumber, capybara, factory-bot

I'm new with BDD approach and I'm studying to put that in all my future projects.

I'm trying to run a simple test in which the user has to be logged to access a specific page (the Create New Fair page) and fill a field form before submit.

It seems I was able to manage login since the test passed but when I try to access Fair page I'm always redirected to the welcome/index for some reason I don't understand. As result of this I receive a "Unable to find button "Create Fair" message in the next next.

Here my files to let you understand my problem:

**fairs.feature:**

```
Feature: Fairs
  In order to create a new Fair
  A user must be logged
  Should fill fair form

  Scenario: Create a new Fair
    Given I'm logged as superuser
    And I'm on the add Fair page
    And I fill in "name"
    When I press "Create Fair"
    Then A new fair should be created with success
```

**create_fair_steps.rb (only steps I've problem with):**

```
Given(/^I'm logged as superuser$/) do
  user = build(:user)
  login_as(user, :scope => :user, :run_callbacks => false)
  #Warden.test_reset!
end

Given(/^I'm on the add Fair page$/) do
  visit('/it/fairs/new')
end

When(/^I press "(.*?)"$/) do |confirm_button|
  #submit_form "new_fair"
  click_button confirm_button
end
```

**users.rb ()**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user, class: User do
    email   "admin@email.com"
    password "superadmin"
  end
end
```

To use FactoryGirl i've added the following line to the **env.rb** file:

```
World(FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods)
```

The **output log**

```
Feature: Fairs
  In order to create a new Fair
  A user must be logged
  Should fill fair form

  Scenario: Create a new Fair                      # features/fairs.feature:6
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  commit transaction
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
    Given I'm logged as superuser                  # features/step_definitions/create_fair_steps.rb:4
Started GET "/it/fairs/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-31 17:50:42 +0200
Processing by FairsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"locale"=>"it"}
Redirected to http://www.example.com/it
Completed 302 Found in 254ms (ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)
Started GET "/it" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-31 17:50:42 +0200
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" IS NULL  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
Processing by WelcomeController#home as HTML
  Parameters: {"locale"=>"it"}
Redirected to http://www.example.com/it/home
Completed 302 Found in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Started GET "/it/home" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-31 17:50:42 +0200
Processing by WelcomeController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"locale"=>"it"}
  Rendered welcome/index.html.erb within layouts/site (3.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 314ms (Views: 298.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
    And I'm on the add Fair page                   # features/step_definitions/create_fair_steps.rb:10
    And I fill in "name"                           # features/step_definitions/create_fair_steps.rb:14
    When I press "Create Fair"                     # features/step_definitions/create_fair_steps.rb:18
      Unable to find button "Create Fair" (Capybara::ElementNotFound)
      ./features/step_definitions/create_fair_steps.rb:20:in `/^I press "(.*?)"$/'
      features/fairs.feature:10:in `When I press "Create Fair"'
    Then A new fair should be created with success # features/step_definitions/create_fair_steps.rb:23
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction

Failing Scenarios:
cucumber features/fairs.feature:6 # Scenario: Create a new Fair

1 scenario (1 failed)
5 steps (1 failed, 1 skipped, 3 passed)
```

If you need more information let me know. Any help is appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: You need to create a user, instead of building a user. build(:user) should be create(:user).

Comment: I've changed to create(:user) but the output now says "it.activerecord.errors.messages.record_invalid"... Maybe it's a devise related problem?

Comment: Does your factory create a record correctly. May be you should test your factory first in your unit test.

Comment: I've solved the last issue.. it was determined by the presence of the record in db, so I cleaned db rerun 'rake cucumber' and everything worked. Thank you